# What's the best way to conditionally define (if not already defined) enumerated commands \cmd1 \cmd2 ... etc?

Tags: conditionals

I am writing a document which contains questions and answers. For example

```
\question{What is 2+3?}{2+3=5}
\question{What is cheese?}{Food made from milk.}
```

The answers are saved up to be gathered in a later section, with the twist that the answers are shuffled to prevent peeking. This means the questions must contain forward-references to the answer numbers. For example:

> Q2.1 What is 2+3? *(See answer 104)*
>
> Q2.2 What is cheese? *(See answer 57)*

I have this *almost* working.

The `\question` command writes all the answers to a temporary file, and a later `\printtheanswers` command sends this to an external program which

a. shuffles the answers,

b. generates Latex for the answers section, and

c. generates an auxiliary file `qa.aux` which defines `\answernumber1`, `\answernumber2` etc to hold the forward-references.

This is a two-pass compilation. The `qa.aux` file is loaded at the beginning, if it exists. The `\question` command must define `\answernumberN` for each of them which does not exist, to expand to a placeholder.

At the moment, `\question` is partially-defined -- it always defines `\answernumberN` to a placeholder:

```
\newcommand{\question}[2]{
    \stepcounter{questionnumber}
    \stepcounter{questionnumberinchapter}

    % Define the placeholder for \answernumberN
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}{PLACEHOLDER:\arabic{questionnumber}}

    % FOR DEBUGGING
    DEFINING \texttt{\textbackslash answernumber\roman{questionnumber} as \{PLACEHOLDER:\arabic{questionnumber}\}}

    % Write "x.y #2" to \qainpfilename
    \immediate\write\qafile{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{questionnumberinchapter} \unexpanded{#2}}

    % Print the qustion to the document.
    Q\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{questionnumberinchapter} #1 \emph{(See answer \expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}.)}
}
```

Here is the line of interest:

```
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}{PLACEHOLDER:\arabic{questionnumber}}
```

The problem is **this ALWAYS defines `\answernumberN`, regardless of whether it is defined in the auxiliary file.**

Here is a MWE, although you can't actually compile it without the external program.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{verbatim}

% Define \bashline command
% Taken from https://gist.github.com/w495/7328b76e76aee49657e0bd7a3b46c870
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\bashline@file@name}[1]{%
        /tmp/${USER}-${HOSTNAME}-\jobname-#1.tex%
    }
    \newread\bashline@file
    \newcommand{\bashline@command@one}[2][tmp]{%
        \immediate\write18{#2 > \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \openin\bashline@file=\bashline@file@name{#1}
        % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
        \bgroup
            \endlinechar=-1
            \read\bashline@file to \localline
            % Since everything in the group is local, 
            % we have to explicitly make the assignment global
            \global\let\bashline@result\localline
        \egroup
        \closein\bashline@file
        % Clean up after ourselves
        \immediate\write18{rm \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \bashline@result
    }
    \newcommand{\bashline@command@many}[2][tmp]{%
        \immediate\write18{#2 > \bashline@file@name{#1}}
        \openin\bashline@file=\bashline@file@name{#1}
        % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
        \newcount\linecnt
        \bgroup
            \endlinechar=-1
            \loop\unless\ifeof\bashline@file 
                \read\bashline@file to \localline%
                \localline
                \newline
            \repeat
        \egroup
        \closein\bashline@file
        % Clean up after ourselves
        \immediate\write18{rm \bashline@file@name{#1}}
    }
    \newcommand{\bashline}[2][tmp]{%
        \bashline@command@one[#1]{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\bashlines}[2][tmp]{%
        \bashline@command@many[#1]{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

% Question-answer stuff.

\def\qainpfilename{qa.inp}
\def\qaauxfilename{qa.aux}
\def\qatexfilename{qa.tex}

\newwrite\qafile
\immediate\openout\qafile=\qainpfilename

\newcounter{questionnumber}
\newcounter{questionnumberinchapter}[chapter]

\newcommand{\question}[2]{
    \stepcounter{questionnumber}
    \stepcounter{questionnumberinchapter}

    % Define the placeholder for \answernumberN
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}{PLACEHOLDER:\arabic{questionnumber}}

    DEFINING \texttt{\textbackslash answernumber\roman{questionnumber} as \{PLACEHOLDER:\arabic{questionnumber}\}}

    % Write "x.y #2" to \qainpfilename
    \immediate\write\qafile{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{questionnumberinchapter} \unexpanded{#2}}

    % Print the qustion to the document.
    Q\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{questionnumberinchapter} #1 \emph{(See answer \expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}.)}
}

\newcommand{\printtheanswers}{
    \immediate\closeout\qafile
    \bashline{bash bin/generate-answers.sh '\qainpfilename' '\qatexfilename' '\qaauxfilename'}

    \input{\qatexfilename}
}

% Demonstrate that this will not be expanded until after qa.tex has been
% generated loaded into the document.
\def\examplething{this is expanded later}



\begin{document}

TEST

\IfFileExists{\qaauxfilename}{\input{\qaauxfilename}}{AUX DOES NOT EXIST}



\chapter{Maths}

\question{What is $1+2$?}{$1+2=3$ \examplething}

\question{What is $2\times 3$?}{$2\times 3=6$}



\chapter{Science}

\question{Name the six quarks.}{Up down, charm, strange, truth, and beauty.}

\question{How many planets orbit the Sun?}{Eight. Deal with it.}



\chapter{Answers}

\printtheanswers

\end{document}
```

The `qa.aux` file which is generated for this document is

```
\def\answernumberi{3}% (Q1.1): $1+2=3$ \examplething 
\def\answernumberii{1}% (Q1.2): $2\times 3=6$
\def\answernumberiii{4}% (Q2.1): Up down, charm, strange, truth, and beauty.
\def\answernumberiv{2}% (Q2.2): Eight. Deal with it.
```

I know you can use `\providecommand` and various if-then constructions, but I haven't been able to get them to work when the command name is constructed with `\expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}`. How do I conditionally define a command whose name is built from a number like this?

Comment: `\expandafter\edef\expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}{PLACEHOLDER:\arabic{questionnumber}}` always defines `\answernumber` not `\answernumberiii` etc.

Comment: can't really tell as the example isn't usable but are you looking for `\expandafter\edef\csname answernumber\roman{questionnumber}\endcsname{PLACEHOLDER:\ar‌​abic{questionnumber}‌​}` ?

Comment: Why do you have `See answer \expandafter\answernumber\roman{questionnumber}`? Why aren't you using `\label{}` and `\ref{}` for cross-references like this?

Comment: @cfr Probably because I don't know how. I only use `\label` for chapter/section numbers. How would it be adapted for counting the nth `\item` in an enumeration?

Comment: Just put it after `\item` e.g. `\item\label{enum:trigqn}` or whatever. Then `\ref{enum:trigqn}` will give you the item's number (or letter or whatever you're using to label them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to cfr, I now use `\label` and `\ref`

The `\question` command now includes

```
Q\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{questionnumberinchapter} #1 \emph{(See answer \expandafter\ref{\expandafter qanswer\arabic{questionnumber}}.)}
```

and the `\printtheanswers` command generates tex like this:

```
\item\label{qanswer123} (text of answer to the 123rd question)
```